# SBT always downloads the packages/scala libraries

Tags: scala, sbt

I have recently installed SBT on Windows XP SP3 machine to get started with Scala. When I started it initially, it started grabbing all the JAR's from the remote locations - pretty much like Maven or any other dependency management tool.

**But**, whenever I change my directory and fire up `sbt`, it again starts downloading the entire solution. Is there a way of maintaining a global cache whereby artifacts are only downloaded once and not every time I change my working directory?

Comment: Actually, it does caches artifacts (to make sure, you can look at `$HOME/.ivy2/cache`). It first looks at the local cache and only then downloads artifact from external repositories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run the same version of sbt in a new directory, it will first look in the local ivy2 cache. It will still *check* all the resources, but will get them locally if they already exist.

However, if you are using SBT extras, it may re-download if you change to a different version of SBT, because it creates a cache for each version. That's my experience on Ubuntu in any case.

What you may have experienced is that some types of sbt plugins, for example sbt-idea, may download additional resources such as source repositories and documentation.

Comment: And in you don't want sbt-idea to download sources and documentation you may run it like `gen-idea no-classifiers`

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Debian), every time I run `sbt` it gets files from `Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.16`. I was not having a local `ivy2` catch. The solution was just to copy the `.ivy2` folder in `/root` to your user home `/home/username` and give access permissions to user.

Comment: This answer helped in indirectly. I was using "sudo docker" commands to run. I realized that if I add my user to the docker group, it would automatically cache the jars. Hence I followed the steps outlined here, 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo